# How to schedule different elements in a 24h range?

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, scheduling

Given the following conditions:

An element has:

- A **time range**, for example: 9:00 to 18:00.
- A **repeat time**, for example: every 5 minutes.

Then a device recieves some elements and has to schedule them in a 0-24h range.

- The device has a minimum **separation time** between elements, for example: 3 minutes (schedules must be separated with at least 3 minutes).

  - However, an element can be immediately followed by another, but it's not desirable. Let's say there's a **max elements per time**. Usually 2 or 3.
- Two elements cannot be scheduled at the same time.
- The repeat time of the schedules can be reduced or incremented if there's no other way to fulfill the separation time requirement, but it's not desirable.

How should the problem be pointed out? Or is there any place I can find information on how similar situations are resolved?

*An example*:

```
One single element:
  time range: 9:00 to 18:00
  time repeat: 5 min

Separation time of the device: 3 min

Result: 9:00, 9:05, ..., 17:55
```

*Another example*:

```
ELEMENT A:
  time range: 9:00 to 18:00
  time repeat: 5 min

ELEMENT B:
  time range: 9:00 to 18:00
  time repeat: 7 min

Separation time of the device: 3 min

Result:
A -> 9:00, 9:06,  9:10, 9:15, 9:21, 9:25, 9:30 
B ->    9:03,     9:10,   9:18,     9:25,   9:33
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: 1. I don't understand how there can be a max elements per time and a separation time.  If events must be separated by at least 3 minutes, that implies it's impossible to have more than 1 event scheduled at any given time.  You even say later two events can't be scheduled at the same time.  What's going on?  How does "max elements per time" make sense?  2.   What does it mean to "increment or decrement" the repeat time?  Can an element with a desired repeat time of 5min occur at 11:00, 11:05, 11:10, 11:14, 11:19, 11:26, etc.?  (i.e., mostly 5 minutes separating it, but sometimes more or less)?

Comment: 3. I still don't understand what requirements a proposed schedule must meet, to be valid.  Suppose the time range is 9:00 to 18:00.  Can I schedule the event at 13:00?  4. If you're going to allow the time between event-occurrences to be a bit more or less than the requested repeat time, then you'll need a way to quantify how good or bad a candidate schedule is.  Is it better to schedule event A 2 minutes late, or better to schedule event B 1 minute late and C 1 minute late?  How do we trade off different possible errors?  You probably need to specify an objective function to maximize.

Comment: 5. You say 2 elements can't be scheduled at the same time, but then yoru second example lists two events scheduled at the same time (e.g., at 9:10).  What's up with that?  It seems like your example contradicts your stated requirements.  6. What does "How should the problem be pointed out?" mean?  Are you looking for an algorithm to find a valid schedule?  7. What approaches have you considered?